# Twitter Bootstrap CSS breaks Minimee

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, minimee

I am using Minimee 2.1.12, and Bootstrap 3.2.0. When I add the bootstrap CSS file to my {exp:minimee:css} tag pair, I am getting an error "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET" in my browser.

I did some whittling down to the CSS file, and narrowed the issue down... This here is the smallest chunk of CSS from that file that will still cause that issue. If I remove any more, the issue doesn't occur... I don't know what about this section of CSS is causing the issue...

```
.table > thead > tr > td.active,
.table > tbody > tr > td.active,
.table > tfoot > tr > td.active,
.table > thead > tr > th.active,
.table > tbody > tr > th.active,
.table > tfoot > tr > th.active,
.table > thead > tr.active > td,
.table > tbody > tr.active > td,
.table > tfoot > tr.active > td,
.table > thead > tr.active > th,
.table > tbody > tr.active > th,
.table > tfoot > tr.active > th {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.table-hover > tbody > tr > td.active:hover,
.table-hover > tbody > tr > th.active:hover,
.table-hover > tbody > tr.active:hover > td,
.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover > .active,
.table-hover > tbody > tr.active:hover > th {
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
}
.table > thead > tr > td.success,
.table > tbody > tr > td.success,
.table > tfoot > tr > td.success,
.table > thead > tr > th.success,
.table > tbody > tr > th.success,
.table > tfoot > tr > th.success,
.table > thead > tr.success > td,
.table > tbody > tr.success > td,
.table > tfoot > tr.success > td,
.table > thead > tr.success > th,
.table > tbody > tr.success > th,
.table > tfoot > tr.success > th {
  background-color: #dff0d8;
}
.table-hover > tbody > tr > td.success:hover,
.table-hover > tbody > tr > th.success:hover,
.table-hover > tbody > tr.success:hover > td,
.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover > .success,
.table-hover > tbody > tr.success:hover > th {
  background-color: #d0e9c6;
}
.table > thead > tr > td.info,
.table > tbody > tr > td.info,
.table > tfoot > tr > td.info,
.table > thead > tr > th.info,
.table > tbody > tr > th.info,
.table > tfoot > tr > th.info,
.table > thead > tr.info > td,
.table > tbody > tr.info > td,
.table > tfoot > tr.info > td,
.table > thead > tr.info > th,
.table > tbody > tr.info > th,
.table > tfoot > tr.info > th {
  background-color: #d9edf7;
}
.table-hover > tbody > tr > td.info:hover,
.table-hover > tbody > tr > th.info:hover,
.table-hover > tbody > tr.info:hover > td,
.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover > .info,
.table-hover > tbody > tr.info:hover > th {
  background-color: #c4e3f3;
}
```

That CSS doesn't break the site unless it's within my minimee tag.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like an issue with the library used to minify the CSS. Try to change it.

Take a look at the [configurations](https://johndwells.github.io/Minimee/#configuration). The default library to is `minify`. Change it to `cssmin`.

In case you're configuring Minimee using `config.php`:

```
/**
 * Specify which minification library to use for your CSS.
 * Values: 'minify' or 'cssmin'
 * Default: minify
 */
'css_library'   => 'cssmin',
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your suggestion. I tried changing the css_library to cssmin, but that didn't fix it. It does, however fix the issue if I set 'minify_css' to 'no'... But I'd rather not lose the minification....